# C# - Lists of Lists

Tags: c#, .net, list

I would like to create a multidimensional list with the following data

[image]

How do I initialize the list and a new class?

I am trying to do the following but when I start adding data how can I link a `tyreID` to a `vehicleID`? Should I create two classes?

```
public class ListName
{
    public int vehicleID { get; set; }
    public string tyresID { get; set; }
}
List<ListName> manID = new List<ListName>();
```

**Edit:**
Thank you for the answers but I am struggling to adapt your suggestions to the following. It is the same logic but I do not find an easy way to write the data into the lists

[image]

```
public class criterias
{
    public double values { get; set; }
    public double time { get; set; }
}

public class movChannels
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public IList<criterias> criteria = new List<criterias>();
}

public class stepsList
{
    public string steps { get; set; }
    public IList<movChannels> stepChannelsCriteria = new List<movChannels>();
}

public class vehicles
{
    public int vehID { get; set; }
    public string vehDescription { get; set; }
    public IList<stepsList> vehValCriteria = new List<stepsList>();
}
```

Now, how can I add the data the I have in the table shown into a list called Vehicles?

Comment: One way to do it is to use grouping: manID.GroupBy(ln=>ln.vehicleID)

Comment: The correct answer to this will create meaningful objects for your domain model, rather than attempting to tie together an bunch of primatives in multidimensional arrays. There we go, like Bruno Garcia's

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a couple classes to represent Tyre and Vehicle:

```
    public class Tyre
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
    public class Vehicle
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public IList<Tyre> Tyres { get; set; } = new List<Tyre>();
    }
```

Something like this:

```
        var vehicles = new[]
        {
            new Vehicle
            {
                Id = "XPT1",
                Tyres = new[]
                {
                    new Tyre {Id = 23},
                    new Tyre {Id = 15},
                }
            },
            new Vehicle
            {
                Id = "OUW2",
                Tyres = new[]
                {
                    new Tyre {Id = 212},
                    new Tyre {Id = 15},
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: Thanks Bruno, How can I insert the values in an easy way into the list. Something like Tyres.Id.Add = 23

Comment: Not sure I understand. The snippet above shows you how you can initialize the list. Perhaps it's more clear like this:        
            var vehicle = new Vehicle { Id = "XPT1" };
            vehicle.Tyres.Add(new Tyre { Id = 23 });

            var vehicles = new List<Vehicle>();
            vehicles.Add(vehicle);

Comment: Please see my edit on the topic. Perhaps I am a bit confused and have shown you a very simple example. Maybe the whole thing helps you better understanding what I need.

Comment: That's basically another question. What's the source of the data? You can do as I did but on a larger scale now (with all those types you created) Although it seems to me a `movChannels` has only 1 `criteria` instead of a List

Comment: I'll delete this one and add another question

Comment: What's the source of the data? Do you want to have this list hardcoded?

Comment: At the moment yes it will be hardcoded, but later it will come from another form or class. Please see new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37271461/c-sharp-adding-data-to-list-inside-list

Answer (score 0):

Why not like this?

```
public class ListName
                {
                    public int vehicleID { get; set; }
                    List<string > TireIds = new List<string>();
                }
```