# C# - Adding data to list inside list

Tags: c#, .net, list

How can I add the following data on the table into a list called Vehicles?

[image]

```
public class criterias
{
    public double values { get; set; }
    public double time { get; set; }
}

public class movChannels
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public IList<criterias> criteria = new List<criterias>();
}

public class stepsList
{
    public string steps { get; set; }
    public IList<movChannels> stepChannelsCriteria = new List<movChannels>();
}

public class vehicles
{
    public int vehID { get; set; }
    public string vehDescription { get; set; }
    public IList<stepsList> vehValCriteria = new List<stepsList>();
}
```

Now, how can I add the data that I have in the table shown into a list called Vehicles? I will create other vehicles later...

Comment: Start with initializing `vehicles` instance and setting its `vehID` and `vehDescription`. Then create `stepsList` instance and add it to `vehValCriteria` `List` and etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You had several bad decisions, some were design flaws and some were minor C# naming convention violations.

**Couple of worth mentions flaws:**

1. **vehID** should have been a **string** and not int (Example "XPT")
2. Movment has Name, Value and Time. It doesn't have a list of Values and Times.

**Creation:**

```
List<Vehicle> vehicles = new List<Vehicle>();

Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle()
{
    Id = "XPT",
    Description = "Average Car",
    Steps = new List<Step>()
    {
        new Step() {
            Name = "move car",
            Movements = new List<Movement>()
            {
                new Movement("engage 1st gear", 1, 1),
                new Movement("reach 10kph", 10, 5),
                new Movement("maintain 10kph", 10, 12),
            }
        },
        new Step() {
            Name = "stop car",
            Movements = new List<Movement>()
            {
                new Movement("reach 0kph", 10, 4),
                new Movement("put in neutral", 0, 1),
                new Movement("turn off vehicle", 0, 0),
            }
        }
    }
};
vehicles.Add(vehicle);
```

**Entities:**

```
public class Movement
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Values { get; private set; }
    public double Time { get; private set; }

    public Movement(string name, double values, double time)
    {
        Name = name;
        Values = values;
        Time = time;
    }
}

public class Step
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Movement> Movements { get; set; }
}

public class Vehicle
{
    public string Id { get; set; } // Should be changed to string
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public IList<Step> Steps { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: cannot use the type var I don't know why

Comment: @peetman, code updated. (Also added `vehicles.Add(...);`) at the end.

Comment: thanks. if I have more than one criteria to each Movement should I just replace the Values and Time with another class as I suggested in the Question?

Comment: @peetman, Indeed, Good job. If you still can't make that happend, tell me and i will refactor. Feel free to upvote and accept if the post answered your question.

Comment: Thanks. How can access the created list in a another class(.cs)?

Comment: Great. I was missing the _public static void Main()_ now how can I access this list in another class. I have create this in a class called HelpClass and I am trying to access by using HelpClass.vehicles but it does not work.

Comment: Different question on different thread. You can find many answers to this question on your favorite search engine (many of the answers will be directed to StackOverflow). Additionally, you can upvote and accept the answer if that helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You should create your classes like the following:

```
public class criterias
{
    public double values { get; set; }
    public double time { get; set; }
}

public class movChannels
{
    public movChannels
    {
        criteria = new List<criterias>();
    }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public IList<criterias> criteria { get; set; }
}

public class stepsList
{
    public stepsList
    {
        stepChannelsCriteria = new List<movChannels>();
    }
    public string steps { get; set; }
    public IList<movChannels> stepChannelsCriteria { get; set; }
}

public class vehicles
{
    public vehicles
    {
        vehValCriteria = new List<stepsList>();
    }
    public int vehID { get; set; }
    public string vehDescription { get; set; }
    public IList<stepsList> vehValCriteria { get; set; }
    public movChannels movments { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about that?

```
public class VehiclesViewModel
{
    public List<vehicles> Vehicles { get; private set; }

    public void Initalize()
    {
      this.Vehicles  = new List<vehicles>();

        var vehicle = new vehicles
                       {
                           vehID = 1,
                           vehDescription = "firstDescription",
                       };
        var stepsList = new stepsList
                        {
                            steps = "firstStep",
                        };
        var movChannel = new movChannels
                          {
                              name = "firstChannel",
                          };
        var criteria = new criterias
                        {
                            values = 0.5,
                            time = 0.5
                        };

        movChannel.criteria.Add(criteria);
        stepsList.stepChannelsCriteria.Add(movChannel);
        vehicle.vehValCriteria.Add(stepsList);

        this.Vehicles.Add(vehicle);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems in your table the VehicleId is of type string. Make sure your VehicleId property in Vehicle class also matches the same.

You can use the collection initializers to set the values of child objects like this way:

```
 var data = new vehicles()
        {
            vehID = 1,
            vehDescription = "Average Car",
            vehValCriteria = new List<stepsList>()
            {
                new stepsList()
                {
                    steps = "Move car",
                    stepChannelsCriteria = new List<movChannels>()
                    {
                        new movChannels()
                        {
                            name = "engage firstgear",
                            criteria = new List<criterias>()
                            {
                                new criterias()
                                {
                                    values = 1,
                                    time = 1
                                },
                            }
                        },
                        new movChannels()
                        {
                            name = "reach 10kph",
                            criteria = new List<criterias>()
                            {
                                new criterias()
                                {
                                    values = 10,
                                    time = 5
                                },
                            }
                        },
                        new movChannels()
                        {
                            name = "maintain 10kph",
                            criteria = new List<criterias>()
                            {
                                new criterias()
                                {
                                    values = 10,
                                    time = 12
                                },
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                new stepsList()
                {
                    steps = "stop car",
                    stepChannelsCriteria = new List<movChannels>()
                    {
                        new movChannels()
                        {
                            name = "reach okph",
                            criteria = new List<criterias>()
                            {
                                new criterias()
                                {
                                    values = 10,
                                    time = 4
                                },
                            }
                        },
                        new movChannels()
                        {
                            name = "put in neutral",
                            criteria = new List<criterias>()
                            {
                                new criterias()
                                {
                                    values = 0,
                                    time = 1
                                },
                            }
                        },
                        new movChannels()
                        {
                            name = "turn off vehicle",
                            criteria = new List<criterias>()
                            {
                                new criterias()
                                {
                                    values = 0,
                                    time = 0
                                },
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fill your list by moving from top to bottom, like

- Create Criterias List then Create movChannel object and add that list
  to Criterias object and so on

However if you want to avoid this way, there is another way. If you are using Linq To List then follow this

Get a simple flat object to a list object

```
var TableData = db.Tablename.Tolist();
```

Then fill your own object like this

```
Vehicles finalList = TableData.Select(a => new Vehicles()
{
    vehID = a.Id,
    vehDescription = a.des,
    vehValCriteria = TableData.Where(b => b.StepslistId == a.StepslistId)
    .Select(c => new StepsList()
    {
                steps = c.Steps,
                stepChannelsCriteria = TableData.Where(d => d.channelId == c.channelId)
                .select(e => new MovChannels()
                {
                    name = e.name,
                    criteria = TableData.Where(f => f.criteriasId = e.criteriasId)
                    .Select(g => new Criterias()
                    {
                        values = g.Values,
                        time = g.Time

                    }).ToList()
                }).ToList()
         }).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

This is standard way to fill list within list