# How add data to list inside list using loop in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

Ho Can i Add data to list in inside list using model in c#,

I have referred code form below url but they are directly entering value, i need to loop through each row?

[C# - Adding data to list inside list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37271461/c-sharp-adding-data-to-list-inside-list)

below is my code

```
public class AllClaimDetails
{
    public class AllClaims
    {
        public string VendID { get; set; }
        public int VendKey { get; set; }
        public string CompanyID { get; set; }
        public IList<ClaimLots> Lots { get; set; }
    }

    public class ClaimLots
    {
        public string LotNo { get; set; }
        public string InvoiceType { get; set; }
        public string TranNo { get; set; }
        public int TranType { get; set; }
        public decimal TranAmount { get; set; }
        public decimal ApplyAmount { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
    }
}

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dt.Load(rdr);

            List<AllClaims> requestObject = new List<AllClaims>();
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                AllClaims claims = new AllClaims()
                {
                    VendID = dt.Rows[i]["VendID"].ToString(),
                    Lots = new List<ClaimLots>()
                    {
                        new ClaimLots{
                            LotNo=dt.Rows[i]["LotNo"].ToString(),
                            TranNo=dt.Rows[i]["TranNo"].ToString(),
                            TranType=Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["TranType"].ToString()),
                            //TranAmount=Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["TranAmt"].ToString()),
                            Status=Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["Status"].ToString())
                        }
                    }
                };
                requestObject.Add(claims);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you.

```
    using System; 
    using System.Collections.Generic; 
      
    class TestList{ 
     
        public static void Main(String[] args) 
        { 
      
            // Creating a List of integers 
            List<int> firstlist = new List<int>(); 
      
            // adding elements in firstlist 
            for (int i = 4; i < 10; i++) { 
                firstlist.Add(i * 2); 
            } 
      
            // Displaying elements of firstlist 
            // by using foreach loop 
            foreach(int element in firstlist) 
            { 
                Console.WriteLine(element); 
            } 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: No its not showing as i excepted, please check above link which i mentioned in question.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to use `IList<T>` instead of `List<T>`  for `Lots`. When you refer to your classes you have neglected to add the containing class. I also tidied up the data code and change your loop to a `foreach`. Not really sure what the problem is.

```
public class AllClaimDetails
{
    public class AllClaims
    {
        public string VendID { get; set; }
        public int VendKey { get; set; }
        public string CompanyID { get; set; }
        public List<ClaimLots> Lots { get; set; }
    }

    public class ClaimLots
    {
        public string LotNo { get; set; }
        public string InvoiceType { get; set; }
        public string TranNo { get; set; }
        public int TranType { get; set; }
        public decimal TranAmount { get; set; }
        public decimal ApplyAmount { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
    }
}
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private string ConStr = "Your connection string"
    private void OPCode()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConStr))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cn.Open();
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        }
        List<AllClaimDetails.AllClaims> requestObject = new List<AllClaimDetails.AllClaims>();
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            AllClaimDetails.AllClaims claims = new AllClaimDetails.AllClaims()
            {
                VendID = row["VendID"].ToString(),
                Lots = new List<AllClaimDetails.ClaimLots>()
                {
                    new AllClaimDetails.ClaimLots{
                        LotNo=row["LotNo"].ToString(),
                        TranNo=row["TranNo"].ToString(),
                        TranType=Convert.ToInt32(row["TranType"].ToString()),
                        Status=Convert.ToInt32(row["Status"].ToString())
                    }
                }
            };
            requestObject.Add(claims);
        }
    }
```